# why can't docker find my own package when deploying via serverless?

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I want to deploy my python package to Amazon and make it available via lambda. For this I'm trying serverless.

When I try to deploy my package I get the following error message:

```
SLS_DEBUG=* serverless deploy --stage dev --aws-profile default
Serverless: Load command config
Serverless: Load command config:credentials
Serverless: Load command create
Serverless: Load command install
Serverless: Load command package
Serverless: Load command deploy
Serverless: Load command deploy:function
Serverless: Load command deploy:list
Serverless: Load command deploy:list:functions
Serverless: Load command invoke
Serverless: Load command invoke:local
Serverless: Load command info
Serverless: Load command logs
Serverless: Load command login
Serverless: Load command logout
Serverless: Load command metrics
Serverless: Load command print
Serverless: Load command remove
Serverless: Load command rollback
Serverless: Load command rollback:function
Serverless: Load command slstats
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:install
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:uninstall
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:list
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:search
Serverless: Load command config
Serverless: Load command config:credentials
Serverless: Load command rollback
Serverless: Load command rollback:function
Serverless: Load command requirements
Serverless: Load command requirements:clean
Serverless: Load command requirements:install
Serverless: Load command requirements:cleanCache
Serverless: Invoke deploy
Serverless: Invoke package
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:validate
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:cleanupTempDir
Serverless: Generated requirements from /home/ola/projects/lambda/tagdoc/requirements.txt in /home/ola/projects/lambda/tagdoc/.serverless/requirements.txt...
Serverless: Installing requirements from /home/ola/projects/lambda/tagdoc/.serverless/requirements/requirements.txt ...
Serverless: Docker Image: lambci/lambda:build-python3.6
Requirement 'pkgg-0.1.0.tar.gz' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Processing ./pkgg-0.1.0.tar.gz
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/task/pkgg-0.1.0.tar.gz'


  Error --------------------------------------------------

  null

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

  Stack Trace --------------------------------------------

Error: null
    at installRequirements (/home/ola/projects/lambda/tagdoc/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:262:11)
    at installRequirementsIfNeeded (/home/ola/projects/lambda/tagdoc/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:448:3)
    at ServerlessPythonRequirements.installAllRequirements (/home/ola/projects/lambda/tagdoc/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:527:29)
From previous event:
    at PluginManager.invoke (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:390:22)
    at PluginManager.spawn (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:408:17)
    at Deploy.BbPromise.bind.then.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/deploy/deploy.js:123:50)
From previous event:
    at Object.before:deploy:deploy [as hook] (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/deploy/deploy.js:113:10)
    at BbPromise.reduce (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:390:55)
From previous event:
    at PluginManager.invoke (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:390:22)
    at PluginManager.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:421:17)
    at variables.populateService.then.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:157:33)
    at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
From previous event:
    at Serverless.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:144:8)
    at serverless.init.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless:43:50)
    at <anonymous>

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     linux
     Node Version:           8.15.0
     Serverless Version:     1.30.1
```

my serverless.yml file looks like this:

```
# Welcome to Serverless!
#
# This file is the main config file for your service.
# It's very minimal at this point and uses default values.
# You can always add more config options for more control.
# We've included some commented out config examples here.
# Just uncomment any of them to get that config option.
#
# For full config options, check the docs:
#    docs.serverless.com
#
# Happy Coding!

service: tagdoc # NOTE: update this with your service name

# You can pin your service to only deploy with a specific Serverless version
# Check out our docs for more details
# frameworkVersion: "=X.X.X"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  region: eu-central-1
# you can overwrite defaults here
#  stage: dev

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

# You need to have Docker installed to be able to set dockerizePip:
# true or dockerizePip: non-linux. Alternatively, you can set
# dockerizePip: false, and it will not use Docker packaging. But,
# Docker packaging is essential if you need to build native packages
# that are part of your dependencies like Psycopg2, NumPy, Pandas, etc
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true

# you can define service wide environment variables here
#  environment:
#    variable1: value1

# you can add packaging information here
package:
  include:
    - ./nltk_data/*

functions:
  ttxt:
    handler: handler.ttxt
    events:
      - http:
          path: /ttxt
          method: get
          integration: lambda
          request:
            template:
              application/json: '{ "txt" : "$input.params(''txt'')" }'
          response:
            headers:
  turl:
    handler: handler.turl
    events:
      - http:
          path: /turl
          method: get
          integration: lambda
          request:
            template:
              application/json: '{ "url" : "$input.params(''url'')" }'
          response:
            headers:
              Content-Type: "'application/json'"
```

and of top the directory includes all the required files, in particular the built python package:

```
tree -L 2 lambda/
lambda/
└── tagdoc
    ├── pkgg-0.1.0.tar.gz
    ├── handler.py
    ├── nltk_data
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package.json
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── README.md
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── serverless.yml
    └── srv

4 directories, 8 files
```

I'm currently running Debian 9.5. I've also shared the code with a friend running the same OS via Github and it seems he can deploy the package. Therefore, it looks it has to do with my local setup of serverless / docker. But I can't figure out how to resolve this. Any help would be really appreciated.

The requirements.txt just contains one line:

```
cat requirements.txt 
pkgg-0.1.0.tar.gz
```

Now the package itself has some dependency. By including only the package it takes the dependencies in the `setup.py` file from the package.

**EDIT**

as asked in one of the comments. This is my `.gitignore`

```
#Compiled source#
#################
*.pyc

# no data files #
################
*.csv

#Log files#
#################
*.log

#swap files#
###############
*.swp
*.*~
\#*\#
.\#*

#django migration directory#
############################
venv*
srv*
theme
collectedstatic
stunnel

# Elastic Beanstalk Files
.elasticbeanstalk/*
!.elasticbeanstalk/*.cfg.yml
!.elasticbeanstalk/*.global.yml

#Serverless package
.serverless
```

and this is how my .serverless looks like. All the requirements.txt have exactly the same content as the one above.

```
tree -L 3 .serverless/
.serverless/
├── cloudformation-template-create-stack.json
├── requirements
│   └── requirements.txt
└── requirements.txt

1 directory, 3 files
```

Comment: can you also add the content of the file requirements.txt. Also can you explain what the file pkgg-0.1.0.tar.gz is needed for?

Comment: @mostafazh I've added the required piece. But as I said, my friend uses the same git commit and is able to deploy to aws. I think it has to do with my local serverless / docker setup

Comment: can you add `SLS_DEBUG=*` to the beginning of the deploy command, before `serverless deploy ...` and update the question

Comment: @mostafazh updated the output in the question including the `SLS_DEBUG=*`. Many thanks for your help

Comment: The logs didn't say much new. Can you clone the github repo in a totally different location and they to deploy from there. You could also run 'serverless remove` on the current directory to delete the function from AWS. Can you also share the git repo URL or at least your `.gitignore` file. Sorry for asking for too much :)

Comment: @mostafazh i've added my .gitignore. Unfortunately, I can't share the repo. I don't want to remove the function from AWS as it is used. No worries, I'm thankful for the help :)

Comment: Can you clone the repo at a different location on your computer and deploy a new function from there ?

Comment: I fear something is wrong inside your .serverless config folder

Comment: @mostafazh I've added the `.serverless` too. I don't think that there is something wrong. But I might be wrong

Comment: Serverless is a folder of many files beside the requirements.txt file. I'd highly recommend you clone the repo in a different folder and test there again

Comment: Try a different docker image

Comment: The error message seems clear, but I cannot see much about docker info, or the way how to install python package. Since the directory you put and the directory from error message are not the same one, I cannot get the point.

Comment: @Light.G That's what I don't get. If I do a simple serverless project following this blog `https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/` I can properly deploy. It might come from the own built package `pkgg`. However, I can install and import it without a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue seems to be within `serverless-python-requirements`. As it looks like with version 4.1.1 it works flawless while with 4.2.5 it doesn't. I raised an issue on github

Comment: can you please put the link the issue on github? @math

Answer (score 1):

`dockerizePip: true` => `pip` will run in the container, which doesn't share the filesystem with your host OS by default, but it can download python packages from the internet. It looks like the plugin `serverless-python-requirements` doesn't mount your local files to the container properly, so `pip` is not able to see your local package (`pkgg-0.1.0.tar.gz`).

IMHO the best solution is not to use local files in the `requirements.txt`.

Cross reference: https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/issues/258

Comment: many thanks for your answer. How can it be that `serverless-python-requirements` doesn't mount my local files? My friend uses the same machine, same os, same repo and can deploy.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a time to dig in the `serverless-python-requirements` code. Which docker run parameters are generated in the backgournd in your and in the friend runs?

Comment: No worries, more than happy to get any help :) what do you mean with `docker run parameters are generated in the background`? I've re-installed yesterday everything. We are now using the same Docker build, same node version, same serverless version.

Answer (score 0):

Project [lambci/lambda](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/) describes itself as `Images that (very closely) mimic the live AWS Lambda environment`, if you want to make sure the environments is 100% compatible, spin up an small t2.micro instance on EC2 , connect via SSH and setup your project there, run `pip install -r requirements.txt`on your shell, download all libraries and dispose the instance. That is exactly what Lambda will do next time it provision [the environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) for running your code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider building in a docker container as described in this serverless [blog post](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/)

Comment: It’s suggestion. Maybe a comment would be proper enough.